swipe and click to show button horizontally align with each other behind recyclerview item
i am creating a RecyclerView list with swipe functionality, the implementation which I want is when the user swipe or click the button over RecyclerView item, that item should swipe about 200px and represent the two buttons behind it which should be horizontally align, also I want to add animation on swipe and un-swipe
I tried item touch helper class and have done the UI to display two button horizontally but the problem which I'm facing is in swipe functionality, its not working properly, is there any guide from where I can get help, thanks
